# How to Remove Text Tag in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this rawhtmlString:

```html
<li class="item-container">
  <div class="item-description-container"><a class="ajax item-title" href="/news/1417">ទស្សនា​រូបភាព​នៅមុន​ជំនួប​រវាង​កម្ពុជា និង​ព្រុយ​ណេ​</a>
    <div class="item-subtitle">
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://thmeythmey.com/?page=detail&amp;ctype=article&amp;id=45654&amp;lg=kh" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://thmeythmey.com/?page=detail&amp;ctype=article&amp;id=45654&amp;lg=kh&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
      </div><span class="postedDate">Thmey Thmey - 1ម៉ោង 43នាទី មុន</span>
    </div>
    <p class="item-description">​ក្រុមកីឡា​បាល់ទាត់​ជម្រើសជាតិ​កម្ពុជា នឹង​ទទួលភ្ញៀវ​ព្រុយ​ណេ នា​វេលា​ម៉ោង​៦ និង​៣០​នាទី សម្រាប់​ការប្រកួត​ជម្រុះ AFF Suzuki Cup នា​ថ្ងៃ​អង្គារ ទី​១៨ ខែតុលា នេះ នៅ​ពហុ​កីឡដ្ឋាន​ជាតិ​អូឡាំពិក​។ ក្រុម​ទាំងពីរ សុទ្ធតែ​បានទទួល​ជ័យជម្នះ​រៀងៗ​ខ្លួន​នា​ការប្រកួត​បើកឆាក
      ដោយ​កម្ពុជា​ឈ្នះ​ឡាវ ២-១ បន្ទាប់ពី​ព្រុយ​ណេ បំបាក់​ទី​ម័​រ​ខាងកើត​ក្នុង​លទ្ធផល​ដូចគ្នា​។​
    </p>
  </div>
  <img class="item-thumbnail" src="https://image.thmeythmey.com/pictures/2016/10/18/thumb1/181020161817cam8.jpg" />
</li>
<li class="item-container">
  <div class="item-description-container"><a class="ajax item-title" href="/news/1416">NGO ជាង ៥០ ប្រារព្ធ​ខួប​២៥​ឆ្នាំ​នៃ​កិច្ចព្រមព្រៀង​ទីក្រុង​ប៉ារីស​</a>
    <div class="item-subtitle">
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://thmeythmey.com/?page=detail&amp;ctype=article&amp;id=45630&amp;lg=kh" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://thmeythmey.com/?page=detail&amp;ctype=article&amp;id=45630&amp;lg=kh&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
      </div><span class="postedDate">Thmey Thmey - 1ម៉ោង 43នាទី មុន</span>
    </div>
    <p class="item-description">​ភ្នំពេញ​៖ សម្ព័ន្ធ​អង្គការក្រៅរដ្ឋាភិបាល​ជាង ៥០ បាន​សហការគ្នា​រៀបចំ​វេទិកា​ថ្នាក់ជាតិ​ស្តីពី ខួប​ទី ២៥​ឆ្នាំ នៃ​កិច្ចព្រមព្រៀង​សន្តិភាព​ទីក្រុង​ប៉ារីស ដើម្បី​ពិនិត្យ​ពី​លទ្ធផល​កិច្ចព្រមព្រៀង និង​បញ្ហា ប្រឈម​របស់​កម្ពុជា បច្ចុប្បន្ន និង​អនាគត​។​</p>
  </div>
  <img class="item-thumbnail" src="https://image.thmeythmey.com/pictures/2016/10/18/thumb1/paris__1_.jpg" />
</li>
<li class="item-container">
  <div class="item-description-container"><a class="ajax item-title" href="/news/1415">​សាលារៀន អន្តរទ្វីប អាមេរិកាំង ដឹកនាំ​លោកគ្រូ អ្នកគ្រូ​ចំនួន​១០០​នាក់​ ​ចុះ​កម្មសិក្សា​នៅ​រោងចក្រ​ផលិត​ទឹកដោះគោ​អង្គរ​</a>
    <div class="item-subtitle">
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://thmeythmey.com/?page=detail&amp;ctype=article&amp;id=45665&amp;lg=kh" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://thmeythmey.com/?page=detail&amp;ctype=article&amp;id=45665&amp;lg=kh&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
      </div><span class="postedDate">Thmey Thmey - 1ម៉ោង 43នាទី មុន</span>
    </div>
    <p class="item-description">​កាលពី​ចុង​សប្តាហ៍​កន្លងទៅ​ថ្មីៗ​នេះ សាលារៀន អន្តរទ្វីប អាមេរិកាំង បាន​ដឹកនាំ​លោកគ្រូ អ្នកគ្រូ និង​បុគ្គលិក​ចំនួន​១០០​នាក់ ចុះ​កម្មសិក្សា​រោងចក្រ​ផលិត​ទឹកដោះគោ​អង្គរ ឌែ​រី ប្រូ​ដាក ស្ថិតនៅក្នុង​តំបន់​សេដ្ឋកិច្ច​ពិសេស ផ្លូវជាតិ​លេខ​៤ ខណ្ឌ​ពោធិ​សែន​ជ័យ
      រាជធានី​ភ្នំពេញ​។​</p>
  </div>
  <img class="item-thumbnail" src="https://image.thmeythmey.com/pictures/2016/10/19/thumb1/a__1_.jpg" />
</li>
<li class="item-container">
  <div class="item-description-container"><a class="ajax item-title" href="/news/1414">រដ្ឋបាល​ក្រុង​សៀមរាប​ប្រាប់​អាជីវករ​ផ្សារលើឲ្យ​រុះរើ​តូប​ដែល​កំពុង​រំលោភ​ផ្លូវ​សាធារណៈ</a>
    <div class="item-subtitle">
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://thmeythmey.com/?page=detail&amp;ctype=article&amp;id=45663&amp;lg=kh" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://thmeythmey.com/?page=detail&amp;ctype=article&amp;id=45663&amp;lg=kh&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
      </div><span class="postedDate">Thmey Thmey - 1ម៉ោង 43នាទី មុន</span>
    </div>
    <p class="item-description">​សៀមរាប​៖ រដ្ឋបាល​ក្រុង​សៀមរាប បានចេញ​សេចក្តីជូនដំណឹង​របស់​ខ្លួន ប្រាប់​ដល់​បណ្តា​អាជីវករ​នៅ​ផ្សារលើ​ធំថ្មី​ទាំងអស់ ដែល​កំពុង​រំលោភ​លើដី​សាធារណៈ ឲ្យ​បញ្ឈប់​ការលក់ដូរ និ រុះរើ​ជាបន្ទាន់​។ សេចក្តីជូនដំណឹង​នេះ ធ្វើឡើង​ក្រោយពេល​ការចុះ​ត្រួតពិនិត្យ​របស់​អាជ្ញាធរ
      និង​ការធ្វើ​ចរាចរណ៍​នៅ​តំបន់​ផ្សារលើ មានការ​កកស្ទះ​ជារឿយៗ ដោយសារ​ការលក់ដូរ​លើ​ចំណីផ្លូវ​សាធារណៈ។​</p>
  </div>
  <img class="item-thumbnail" src="https://image.thmeythmey.com/pictures/2016/10/19/thumb1/xxcc.jpg" />
</li>
```

When I parse it to html by using this function $(rawhtmlString) or this $.parseHtml(rawhtmlString). 
I got it rendered correctly in the browser like below:

[image]

However, when I console.log it 

`var dataHtml = $(rawhtmlString);
console.log(dataHtml);`

I got this new text tag which I don't expect:

[image]

My purpose is to loop all through the li element and parse it to FB.XFBML.parse();

I can loop through all them, and skip the even number which would be work, but i don't like that solution.

My question is: What have I done wrong? Why this text tag appears in console.log but not in Elements? How to remove it? or How to convert parse rawhtmlString without that text element?

Thanks,

Comment: Try `$(rawhtmlString).find('li').each(function(index, element){})`

Comment: It's not working. The loop is not executing.

Comment: I got it working by doing this: `dataHtml.find('li').addBack('li').each(function( index, element ) {
        FB.XFBML.parse($(this)[0]);
       });`